Conditional Expectation of dependent normal distribution
Suppose we have $Z_0, Z_1, Z_2$ all standard normal distributed and independent. And $ X = c+aZ_0 + aZ_1$ and $Y=c+aZ_0+aZ_2$ for $a,c \ge 0$. Is there a way to calculate $E[Y|X]$ only using properties of the conditional expectation and the normal distribution, however not the multivariate normal distribution?
Any help would be much appreciated.

We have $X-aZ_1=Y-aZ_2$, so condition both sides with respect to $X$. This gives
$$
X -aE(Z_1\mid X) = E(Y\mid X) -a E(Z_2\mid X).
$$
By independence we have $E(Z_2\mid X)=E(Z_2)=0$ while $$E(Z_1\mid X)\stackrel{(1)}=E(Z_1\mid Z_0+Z_1)\stackrel{(2)}=\frac12(Z_0 + Z_1)=\frac12\frac{X-c}a.$$ Step (1) follows because $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Z_0+Z_1)$, while step (2) follows from symmetry: $E(Z_0\mid Z_0+Z_1)=E(Z_1\mid Z_0+Z_1)$ and the sum of these two equals $Z_0+Z_1$.
Now simplify and solve for
$$E(Y\mid X)=\frac12(X+c).$$
Note this argument uses the fact that the $Z$'s are iid with zero mean, but not that they are Gaussian.

Thanks. I really like the simplicity. It seems so obvious now

Without loss of generality, assume that $c=0$ and $a=1$.
Let us find $K$ such that
$$
\operatorname{Cov}\left(Y-KX,X\right)=0.
$$
Since $(X,Y)$ is a Gaussian vector, this will imply that $Y-KX$ is independent of $X$ hence
$$
\mathbb E\left[Y\mid X\right]=\mathbb E\left[Y-KX\mid X\right]+
\mathbb E\left[KX\mid X\right]=KX.
$$
Replacing $X$ and $Y$ by their expression in terms of $X_0,X_1$ and $X_2$ gives that $\operatorname{Cov}\left(Y-KX,X\right)=1-2K$ hence the wanted conditional expectation is $X/2$.
